# Catching mouse events outside of an iframe on Internet Explorer (drag-end)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, hammer.js

I'm trying catch a 'drag-end' event of a drag gesture that starts inside an iframe element and end outside of the iframe, or even outside of the browser window (I'm using jQuery and Hammer.js). It seem to work well on all major browsers except Internet Explorer (I have IE11 latest). Here is a demo code I was using to investigate the issue:

**Below is the index.html code, that hosts the iframe:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="iframe.html" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Below is the iframe.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content" style="background-color: #FF0000; width: 300px; height: 300px">
Some Content.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Below is the main.js code, that registers the dragend event listener:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Hammer($("#content").get(0)).on("dragend", function(event) {
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

How can it be fixed so it will work on internet explorer? (it works on great on Chrome, Firefox and Opera). I'm using latest versions of IE, jQuery and Hammer.js.

Thanks much!